# Input Field Data Erased After Datepicker Select

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datepicker

I have an error in my code that I can't figure out why it's happening.

I have 3 input fields. The first two have onclick functions and the last one is for the datepicker. I have no problem with the first two but when I click the datepicker input field and select a month, it erases the first 2 values except the last.

Here's the view code:

```
<div id="location" style="padding:10px;">
  Select Location:
   <input type="text" name="location_name" id="location_name" onclick="loadModuleFormMed('<?php echo $this->config->item('8L_INDEX'); ?>/cms/reports/user_form')" value="<?php echo $location_name; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="location_uuid" id="location_uuid" value="<?php echo $location_uuid; ?>">
</div>
<div id="for_employee" style="padding:10px;">
  Select Employee:
  <input type="text" id="employee_name" name="employee_name" onclick="loadModuleFormMed('<?php echo $this->config->item('8L_INDEX'); ?>/cms/reports/employee/'+$('#location_uuid').val())" disabled="<?php echo $disable; ?>" value="<?php echo $employee_name; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="employee_uuid" id="employee_uuid" value="<?php echo $employee_uuid; ?>">
</div>
<div style="padding:10px;">
  Select Date: <input id="date_select" name="date_select" type="text" value="<?php echo $date_range; ?>">
</div>
```

And here's the script for my datepicker:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('#date_select').datepicker({
language: 'en',
format: "yyyy-mm",
viewMode: "months", 
minViewMode: "months"
});
});
</script>
```

Has anyone encountered something like this? Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was a javascript conflict. I just have to include my table id in my onclick function in my modals.

```
<script>
$('#user_picker_table tr').click(function() {
 //options
});
</script>
```